# check for and plot correlation of string properties in R

Tags: r, plot, correlation

I need to **check for** and **plot** correlance between few properties in R, where many of them are String-based.

Consider the following CSV example data extract for webpage hits:

```
id;type;lang
1;EN;browser
2;EN;ios
3;DE;android
4;DE;browser
5;FR;ios
```

the *type* and *lang* columns contain only strings, and (as far as I understand) cannot be used for plotting or correlation analysis. So I would need to convert them into numbers, right? But how do I reattach the string when plotting language against browser type?

If I consider some methods like PCA, are they even possible with number-converted strings, as there is no useful information in the distance or distribution that way?

Comment: I think this really depends on the question you want to answer in the end. How would you interpret a correlation coefficent (whether it be spearman or pearson) in this context?

Comment: Do you mean something like http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_discrete.html ? However, checking correlation between categorical variables involves other methods instead of the usual correlation coefficient. Like a Chi-squared test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, a great solution is to create an if/else statement. You will compare the strings, and you assign a auxiliar variable a number for each string.

Now, when you have your numbers in a list or in a vector, you can create a new data frame with the number values. After that you can represent your plot.

Here it's your code:

```
id<-c(1:5)
lang<-c("EN","EN","DE","DE","FR")
type<-c("browser","ios","android","browser","ios")


data<-data.frame(id,type,lang)

tmp<-vector(mode="list",length=nrow(data))
auxType<-NULL
auxLang<-NULL

for(i in 1:nrow(data))
{
  #Assign lang
  if(data$lang[i]=="EN")
    auxLang<-1
  else
      if(data$lang[i]=="DE")
        auxLang<-2
      else    
        if(data$lang[i]=="FR")
          auxLang<-3

  #Assign type
  if(data$type[i]=="browser")
    auxType<-1
  else
    if(data$type[i]=="ios")
      auxType<-2
    else
        if(data$lang[i]=="android")
          auxType<-3

  #Create an auxiliar data frame    
  tmp[[i]]<-data.frame(data$id[i],auxType,auxLang)


}

allData<-do.call(rbind,tmp)

names(allData)<-c("id","types","lang")
```

Comment: Can't you just do `data[-1] <- lapply(data[-1], factor, labels = 1:3)` instead of all of this loop and `if` statements?